# Can Monsanto's (in)famous hybrid seed crops be cloned/grafted? If not, is there a technical or legal reason?

Tags: genetics, botany, molecular-genetics, plant-physiology, agriculture

I understand that the seeds of a crop made from modern-day super hybrids will not, usually, produce the same quality plants in the next generation. Therefore, farmers have to buy new hybrid seeds each year (or season) from the original company. But, what if a farmer tried to clone his extremely productive plants?

Is there a scientific reason why modern hybrid varieties cannot be 'grafted', to create next season's high-quality crop, or is it due to a contract agreement signed by the farmers with their seed company? I am very curious as to why modern 'hybrid' crops cannot be propagated in this way.

Comment: Yes, it's stipulated very clearly in the contracts that any such efforts are strictly prohibited. Besides, would you want to graft an entire corn field?

Comment: I last worked on maize a mumble decades ago, but as far as I know grafting in grain producing grasses isn't practical. Please look for evidence that this is possible or if you meant some other type of plant please be specific. ——— Also note that the legal aspects of your question are off-topic for this site.

Comment: One needs to take into account how much work and research would go in cloning these productive plants - this is a task that Monsanto could handle, but probably not a single farmer. Also note the underlying misconception about how the capitalism works: if there was a way to to make these crops more productive, Monsanto would have already done  so and would charge a higher price for them. And if they tried to hide this knowledge in order to keep selling more lower quality crops, they would be quickly bypassed by their competitors or the farmers cloning the crops illegally.

Comment: You’re not even allowed to replant the seeds from the crop you harvested the year before.

Comment: @canadianer If the crop was a hybrid, there's not much point to replanting with the seeds, as they will all be different genetically.

Comment: My understanding is that at least some of it is due to F1 genetics, the F(n) generations will be different